# How to add a database locally in NetStandard2.0 project with VS2017

Tags: database, wpf, visual-studio-2017, local, .net-standard

I have a question, I am not sure if this is possible.
I am creating a project in visual studio 2017 (WPF / c#), with several layers.

- Model (Net Standard 2.0)
- Domain (Net Standard 2.0) (EF)
- BusinessServices (Net Standard 2.0)
- Api (Net Standard 2.0)
- WPF (Net FrameWork 4.7)

I need to add a database locally in the Domain layer who works with EF.
Seems that if a add new item Service-Based Database it won´t work.

Can you advise me want can I do, or maybe should I use a another free database to attach to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pick an embedded database (SQLite, SQL CE, etc) that has a database provider that works with netstandard and EntityFrameworkCore. Both of the ones I suggested above have this.

Here is an example of getting started with SQLite:

- Install and configure EntityFrameworkCore through the usual means. Also install [`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite/).
- Add your database context to the services instance `services.AddDbContext<MvcMovieContext>(options => options.UseSqlite("Data Source=YourDbPath.db"));`
- Done. Everything else will be regular entity framework configuration, so check the entity framework getting started documentation for help with that. Here is a getting started guide that uses `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` but you can substitute the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite` package and follow it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/

Comment: Hello Caesay, thanks a lot, you saved my day :) Have a nice day.